# Registration page should be route on /auth/register and display the message but it isn't getting redirected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a registration page but I'm having a problem after submitting. The page is not getting redirected and the page keeps loading until I refresh the page. I want it to be route on  `/auth/register` and display the message

server.js page

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = express();
var path = require("path"); 
var port = 8080;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());  
app.set("view engine" , "hbs");

const routes = require("./routes/register.js");
app.use("/" ,routes);
app.use("/auth" , require("./routes/auth.js"));   
app.listen(port);
```

index.hbs

```
<form action="/auth/register" method="POST">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name">
    Mobile :<input type="text" name="mobile">
    Password :<input type="password" name="password">
    <button class="saveBtn finModBtn" id="regConfirm">Confirm</button>
    <button class="closeBtn finModBtn" id="regCancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Routing pages

auth.js

After submitting, I want the message to be displayed on this page:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var authController = require("../controller/auth.js");    

router.post("/register" , function(req,res){
    authController.register;
});

module.exports = router;
```

controller page

auth.js controller file

```
exports.register = function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("form submitted");   
}
```

I think there is some mistake in auth.js file of routing but am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this change in /routes/auth.js

`authController.register(req,res);`

Comment: thanks it helped but can you tell me why the code i wrote wasn't working.
@Abhishoya Lunavat

Comment: You hadn't used parentheses which invoke a function or passed the req, res objects which are to be consumed. To see more how functions work in javascript this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) might help.